# Cant install PIAF, issue with 'stopping ntp services'

Tags: freepbx

Im having failure to install PIAF 3 or PIAF 3.1.6. It hangs at the 'stopping ntp services'. Both times I tried clean install from scratch. After 5 mins I ctrl-C then it picks back up, but fails later when again it hangs 'stopping ntp services'.
Any ideas anyone?

```
CentOS 6.7 64Bit minimal
Green 3.1.6 033015
```

running on a DELL desktop T20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open new terminal.

  service ntpd stop
- You will see installation will continue where it was stuck.
- Repeat it until when ever script hang while 'stopping ntp services'

It works perfectly file with me, hope it will solve your problem as well. Keep me posted.